# Mars MIPS Simulator 4.5 Locks up on User Input read-string syscall

Tags: assembly, mips, user-input, mars-simulator, qtspim

Does anyone use the Mars SPIM simulator ?  I have used it for small MIPS 32 programs in school and I like to debug with Mars.  However, I have an program that works on the QtSPIM simulator, but locks up the Mars simulator.  I have removed the irrelevant code from the code below.  In Mars, when the user is prompted for a string, the simulator accepts one character of the string and stops.  QtSPIM accepts an entire string.  (NOTE: If some of the initialization seems odd, please ignore that, I was using that for other debug purposes in the removed code).  At this point, I am wondering if I have exceeded a Mars memory limit ?  Does anyone have a solution ?

```
###############################################################
# 
#  Runninng on Windows 7 64-bit 
# 
#  Works fine on QtSPIM v9.1.17 
# 
#  Locks up on user input in Mars 4.5 
# 
#  Program Start.  
# 
###############################################################
.data
banner1:    .asciiz "          From Rome to Arabia            " 
banner2:    .asciiz "Roman Numeral to Arabic Numeral Converter" 
prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter the Roman Numeral : "
newline:    .asciiz "\n"
output1:    .asciiz "\nThe Arabic  equivalent is " 
remind1:    .asciiz "Uppercase characters IVXLCDM are valid."
terminate:  .asciiz "Program terminated.\n"

userString:
    .space 16                          # Def 16 bytes for user input string 

stack:
    .space 16                          # Def 16 bytes for the stack 

    .globl main

    .text

###############################################################
#
# Begin program execution. 
# 
###############################################################
main:
    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    banner1            # Print the program title banner 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    newline            # Print blank line for aesthetics 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    newline            # Print blank line for aesthetics 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    remind1            # Remind user of valid int values 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    newline            # Print blank line for aesthetics 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

###############################################################
# 
# Initialize the variables used throughout this program. 
# 
###############################################################

    move    $t0,    $0                 # Initialize the newline character 
                                       # value to zero (0) 

    move    $t1,    $0                 # Init the initial stack pointer 
                                       # address value to zero (0) 

    move    $t2,    $0                 # Init the initial stack pointer 
                                       # address value to zero (0) 

    move    $t3,    $0                 # Init the address of the user 
                                       # input string value to zero (0) 

    move    $t4,    $0                 # Init the current character 
                                       # address byte value to zero (0) 

    move    $t5,    $0                 # Init the previous decimal 
                                       # equivalent value to zero (0) 

    move    $t6,    $0                 # Init the sum of the decimal  
                                       # equivalent values to zero (0) 

    move    $t7,    $0                 # Init the procedure variable 
                                       # for the decimal value to zero (0) 

    move    $t7,    $0                 # Init the procedure variable   
                                       # for the character value to zero (0) 

    move    $a0,    $0                 # Init the storage variable 
                                       # for the return value to zero (0)  

    move    $v0,    $0                 # Init the storage variable   
                                       # for the syscal values to zero (0) 

###############################################################
# 
# Get Roman Numeral string from the user.  
# 
###############################################################

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    newline            # Print blank line for aesthetics 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    prompt1            # Prompt for Roman Numeral string  
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    addi    $t0,    $zero,       10    # Store the ASCII newline character 

    la      $t1,    stack              # Load stack pointer address to $t1 
    move    $t2,    $t1                # Load init stack pointer address to 
                                       # $t2 for reference. 

    la      $t3,    userString         # Load address of user input string 

    li      $v0,    8                  # Load Syscall to read string 
    move    $a0,    $t3                # Move input address to syscall var 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    lb      $t4,    0($t3)             # Load current character address and  
                                       # sign extend to $t4 

    bne     $t3,    $t0,       PUSH    # Check for newline terminator before 
                                       # evaluating string. If user entered 
                                       # some characters then jump to the 
                                       # PUSH label 

    j       DONE                       # User entered a blank string so end 
                                       # the program 

###############################################################
# 
# NOTE: 
#       In my opinion, the algorithm to convert from Roman Numerals to 
#       their Arabic (or, decimal ) equivalents is better accomplished 
#       once the string value of the Roman Numeral is reversed.  This 
#       is a design decision that was followed below.  
# 
###############################################################
###############################################################
# 
# Push the characters of the user string on to a stack until the 
# newline character is encounterd. 
# 
###############################################################
PUSH:
    sb      $t4,   0($t1)              # Add current character to the stack 

    addi    $t1,    $t1,          1    # Increment the stack pointer 

    addi    $t3,    $t3,          1    # Get  current character address 

    lb      $t4,    0($t3)             # Load current character value 

    bne     $t4,    $t0,       PUSH    # If the current character value is 
                                       # the newline character then all of 
                                       # the Roman Numerals are on the 
                                       # stack and ready for evaluation 

###############################################################
# 
# Initialize the sum of the decimal equivalent values and the previous 
# decimal equivalent value to zero (0) 
# 
###############################################################
    move    $t6,    $0                 # Initialize the sum of the decimal  
                                       # equivalent values to zero (0) 

    move    $t5,    $0                 # Initialize the previous decimal 
                                       # equivalent value to zero (0) 

###############################################################
# 
#  Display a message to the user and terminate the program.  
# 
###############################################################
DONE:

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    newline            # Print a blank line for aesthetics 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    li      $v0,    4                  # Load Syscall to print string 
    la      $a0,    terminate          # Program termination string  
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction 

    li      $v0,    10                 # Syscall 10 for program exit 
    syscall                            # Execute the syscall instruction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using system call 8 properly. From [the documentation](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html):

> **Arguments**
>
> ```
> $a0 = address of input buffer
> $a1 = maximum number of characters to read
> ```

So you need an `li $a1, 16` prior to `syscall` when reading the string into `userString`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that solved it. I am amazed at the things I learn the hard way, lol.  I completely missed that in the documentation.